# Call Function in RootviewController to AppDelegate

Tags: ios

I have an some `RootviewControllers` and of course a App Delegate. On my App Delegate I switch to all Controllers I want.

Now, I want to disable GPS, if the User presses the Done Button on the App Delegate (-IBAction Deklaration). How can I call that function from my RVC.

I have seen that Sample

```
MyAppDelegate *delegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

but I not really understand what it does.

On my RootViewController I want that this

```
[self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:NO];
```

will be executed in App Delegate in this Function

```
-(IBAction) btnLocationDone {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.7];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown 
                           forView:MainView cache:YES];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [MainWindow addSubview:MainView];
    [LocationWindow setHidden:YES];
    [MainWindow setHidden:NO];
    [LocationWindow removeFromSuperview]; 

}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are asking, and the nature of the question implies that you need to develop a better understanding of iOS application architectures.  UI interactions should be done in `UIViewController` subclasses only, and not in your `UIApplication` delegate, which should be responsible only for (as is apparent from the name) delegate functions from the `UIApplication`, which includes start up and shut down processing.

There is no reason that the method `btnLocationDone` should be in your app delegate; it would be better placed in, for example, a shared superclass of your `UIViewController`, or in a coordinating object, depending on your choice of architecture.

It is strongly recommended that only class names start with capital letters.

If you want to execute `btnLocationDone` in your app delegate when an `IBAction` is called in a view controller, you could just do:

```
- (IBAction)done {
    [self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:NO];
    MyAppDelegate *delegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [delegate btnLocationDone];
}
```

Comment: Thank you that helped me a lot (I am totally new at iPhone Development). I will follow your adivse, if i write the next application. But for the moment, is apple rejecting my App if I do this IBActions from my AppDelegate?

Comment: Apple won't reject an app because  it is poorly structured; however, a poorly structured app is likely to have other problems that could cause it to be rejected.  It would be a good idea for you to read up on MVC (proper, Smalltalk/Objective-C style MVC), and to review some of Apple's examples, which are usually well formed.